# Sum only the numeric parts in a list

Tags: r

I want to create a function that will take a list (we can call it x) and then sum together all of the numeric elements from the list. This should be pretty straightforward I believe, but as I am fairly new to R programming I have not been successful.
We already have a matrix function created

```
a_matrix <- function(){
   matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
}
```

And let's say our list is as following:

```
my_list <- function(){
   list(topic = "brand", c(1.04, 45, 87, 12), a_matrix)
}
```

An I want to sum the numeric values (so not topic = "brand"). i was thinking of using if and else and use `is.numeric` in a function like the one here:

```
sum_num <- function(x){
   
}
```

And then when I run my `sum_num`-function as below, I want to get one value that is the sum of every numeric value.

```
the_list <- my_list()
sum_num(x = the_list)
sum_num(x = the_list [2])
```

I was thinking I could also utilise `sum(x, na.rm = FALSE, …)`, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Please stop writing functions without any input arguments e.g. `my_list` and `a_matrix` ;)

Comment: But I do input `my_list` and `a_matrix`, or what do you mean? I am fairly new to R so I have not learned a lot yet. I just try to do semi-simple functions as practise.

Comment: Just write an assignment expression `a_matrix <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)`. Functions are for grouping many lines of code performing several transformations on the input data.

Comment: Oh okay, I just did it as a function for more practise on functions in general. But I see what you mean, thanks for the comment, I will keep it in mind for the future!

Answer (score 1):

Does this do the trick??

```
test= function(i){
  if(is.numeric(i)){
    return(sum(i))
  }
}
unlist(lapply(the_list, test))
```

output:

```
145.04
```

If you want to take into account the matrix:

```
sum(unlist(lapply(the_list, test)))
```

output:

```
190.04
```

If you want to have it all in one call:

```
test= function(i){
  if(is.numeric(i)){
    return(sum(i))
  }
}

 sum_num= function(j)(sum(unlist(lapply(j, test))))


sum_num(the_list)
```

Comment: I seem to get a vector of two values when i use this, looks like it is one for 'the_list' and one for 'test'.

Comment: what does it look like? because test is just the function so it should not give back 2 value, did the 2nd option do the same?

Comment: the 2nd option worked as it gave only one value, which was desired, but when I try `test(x = the_list)`, nothing comes up

Comment: Ok then use the last option I just added to my answer and let me know if it works

Comment: It does kind of work, I adjusted the code a little and played around with it to get it to do exactly my desired output, but thanks a lot, it helped me!

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

sum_list <- function(x) {
  x %>%
    flatten() %>%
    keep(is.numeric) %>%
    reduce(sum) 
}

sum_list(
  list(topic = "brand", c(1.04, 45, 87, 12), matrix(1:9, nrow = 3))
)
#> [1] 190.04
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified it in my question, but I haven't really started to use libraries yet, do you know how to do it without a library? Because I don't really follow what you have done even though I am sure it is very good. But for this moment in time I'm just trying to do the basics without libraries.

Comment: Execute the R expression `install.packages("tidyverse")` to install the library. There are two dialects of R: base and tidyverse. The latter one aims for readability and is probably easier to learn. You can start by reading [this free book](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/introduction.html)